# How can I customize Ant Design Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, project, antd

I am working on a react project and using Ant Design along with it. The issue that I was facing is that I wanted to customize the components i.e. override some styles like padding, margins, etc. I looked upon the internet and couldn't find relevant material. It would be great if someone could guide me through it. I went through the documentation as well but it was not clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add the `className` property of your Ant Design component. and apply CSS to that class.

Comment: you can check this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620712/how-to-customize-ant-design-styles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259713/how-do-i-change-or-override-a-antd-element-style/70260058#70260058

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.